Update Set for a column
This is a sample table and I would like to update the column 'TYPE' as like the value which is there 'STOCKIN' /'STOCKOUT' for the particular DOCNUM in each row.
Sample Table



CODE
DOCNUM
TYPE




Z01
NUM12
stockin


Z01
NUM12
null


Z01
NUM12
null


Z01
NUM12
null


Z01
NUM134
stockout


Z01
NUM134
null


Z01
NUM134
null


Z01
NUM134
null



Expected table



CODE
DOCNUM
TYPE




Z01
NUM12
stockin


Z01
NUM12
stockin


Z01
NUM12
stockin


Z01
NUM12
stockin


Z01
NUM134
stockout


Z01
NUM134
stockout


Z01
NUM134
stockout


Z01
NUM134
stockout



Please help me how can I update the column Type for each row as per the DOCNUM.

What's the logic to fill those rows? First not null value, min value, max value, anything else? Your question is too vague.

To update the ‘TYPE’ column based on the ‘DOCNUM’ in your table, you can use SQL to achieve this. Here’s a simple SQL query to update the table.
UPDATE sample_table
SET TYPE = (
    SELECT DISTINCT TYPE
    FROM sample_table AS t2
    WHERE t2.DOCNUM = sample_table.DOCNUM
    AND t2.TYPE IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE TYPE IS NULL;

click here to see full code 
